# I use PStricks to draw my picture but the curve is folded. Help me!

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-func,pst-plot,pst-eucl,pstricks-add,pst-node,multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm]{geometry}

\def\coeff{0 -5 0 1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,griddots=10]
  \psset{yunit=0.5}
  \psaxes[Dy=2.5]{->}(0,0)(-5,-10)(5,10)
  \psPolynomial[dotscale=2,linewidth=2pt,linecolor=red,markZeros,coeff=0 -5 0 1]{-5}{5}
\end{pspicture*}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I am not a Pstricks user, so cannot be of much help. Can you choose the sample size? In other words, how far the data points are apart?

Comment: I have no problem compiling with `xelatex`. The traditional way works up to dvips works, but pstopdf has an error message. However , manual conversion via `gsview6` (nder Windows) works fine. Last,pdflatex+ --shell-escape` yields a blank page.

Comment: The first question with PSTricks by me .... :-) I will delete my account. Thank for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set `plotpoints` to a larger value:

```
\psPolynomial[dotscale=2,linewidth=2pt,linecolor=red,
  plotpoints=1000,markZeros,coeff=0 -5 0 1]{-5}{5}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the Pstricks User's Guide suppose, can replace "plotpoints=1000" is "plotstyle=curve" . :-))

Comment: sure, but it depends on what you want. `plotstyle=curve` makes only sense for curves with a slow slope.